# Finding all continuity and differentiability points of a function

Tags: limits, derivatives, continuity

Let $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2(x^2-1),&x \in\mathbb{Q}
\\
0,&x \not\in\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$$

A. When is this function continuous? when is it differentiable?

I solved these kind of excercises, but never when I have $x\in$\ $\not\in \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: The function is continuous at 3 points, which we can find by considering $x^{2}(x^{2}-1)=0$, giving us: $x=\{0,\pm 1\}$. We have that it is differentiable at $x=0$ only.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**: (a) By definition, a function is continuous at $x_0$ iff $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$, for your function, you need hence $$  0 = \lim_{x\to x_0, x\not\in \mathbb Q} f(x) \stackrel != \lim_{x\to x_0, x\in \mathbb Q} f(x) = x_0^2(x_0^2 - 1) $$
(b) If $f$ is not continous, it is not differentiable at $x_0$. To check differentiability at $x_0$ argue as in (a), but for 
$$ \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} $$
instead of $\lim f(x)$.

Comment: Didn't get the part $$\lim_{x\to x_0, x\not\in \mathbb Q} f(x) \stackrel != \lim_{x\to x_0, x\in \mathbb Q} f(x)$$

and why doesn't it differentiable at $\pm 1$

Comment: If this holds, the limit exists ... (as the limits on and off $\mathbb Q$ are equal) ...